# Link on image that has another background-image doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following website http://geertsprengers.be
However I wanted to make the top pictures link to a website, so I replaced the href's from # to the respective websites. If I click them they don't link. How is this possible and what is the solution? I tried wrapping another a element around it but that didn't work.

I think it has something to do with the css of the images' background, however I'm no expert in css so I don't know how I can modify this.

This is the html code:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="">
            <a class="sub" href="http://sublimmo.be">

                <span></span>
           </a>
        </li> 
        <li class="">
            <a class="troga" href="http://troga.be">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="sos" href="#">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="res" href="http://rescotec.com">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS, and a JSFiddle is always helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the return false from the onclick function in the js it will execute properly, returning false is not triggering the click event to its child element

Something like this

```
$(".container li").each(function() 
{
   this.onclick = function() 
   {
        $(".container li").removeClass("tab-current");
        $(this).addClass("tab-current");
        $.ajax({
            url: "getDetails.php?LiID="+this.id
        }).done(function(data){
            $(".description").empty().append(data);
        });
        return true;
    };
});
```

Comment: I just removed the return line and now everything works. However my text isn't displaying properly, ë becomes a question mark. A new bug lol :D in the meantime I fixed this also, it was the encoding of the file that switched to ANSI instead of UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Change tour `wrapper` class in your css to

```
.wrapper {
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```